# IEnumerable to datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ienumerable

Please tell me how to write the result of a query in a DataTable?

```
var result = from clients in Clients_dt.AsEnumerable()
             join cities in Cities_dt.AsEnumerable()
                  on clients.Field<int> ("CityId") equals cities.Field<int> ("ID") into ClientCityGroup
             from subCities in ClientCityGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new 
                    {
                        Name = clients.Field <string> ("Name"),
                        City = subCities.Field <string> ("Name")
                    };
```

I tried using `CopyToDatatable()`.

Comment: *Please tell me how* -- That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

CopyToDataTable only works if the input is a DataTable.  You have to create the DataTable before you can add data to the table.

```
Public DataTable GetTable(var results)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
   dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));

   foreach(var row in result)
   {
     dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { row.Name, row.City });
   }
   return dt;
}
```

Comment: How can I change the code so that the 'result' variable immediately returns a datatable? I tried to change 'select new' to 'select subCities', but in this case it only returns a table with cities.

Comment: You can't.  The query needs to return results in the SELECT.  It cannot be a DataTable, only rows.  If you want to return a table put the code into a Method and make the return of the method a DataTable.

Comment: Please write an example.